# How prove this is an equilateral triangle

Tags: trigonometry

in $\Delta ABC$,$AB=c,AC=b,BC=a$and such

> $$ab^2\cos{A}=bc^2\cos{B}=ca^2\cos{C}$$

show that
$\Delta ABC$ is an equilateral triangle

this problem I have solution,But not nice, and  I think this problem have more nice methods,Thank you everyone.

**my solution:**
$$ab^2\cdot\dfrac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc}=bc^2\cdot\dfrac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}=ca^2\cdot\dfrac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}$$
$$\Longrightarrow a=b=c$$

**My other idea:**

> $$\Longleftrightarrow\dfrac{\sin{B}}{\sin{C}}\cos{A}=\dfrac{\sin{C}}{\sin{A}}\cos{B}=\dfrac{\sin{A}}{\sin{B}}\cos{C}$$
>   $$\Longleftrightarrow \sin{(2A)}\sin{B}=\sin{(2B)}\sin{C}=\sin{(2C)}\sin{A}$$
>   then How prove
>   $$A=B=C$$
>   and have other nice methods? Thank you

Comment: Can you show more details of your solution, so that I can understand what you consider 'not nice'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dividing throughout by $abc$, we get

$$ \frac{b^2+c^2 - a^2}{c^2} = \frac{a^2 + c^2 - b^2}{a^2} = \frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{b^2}.$$

Subtracting 1 from each term,

$$ \frac{b^2- a^2}{c^2} = \frac{ c^2 - b^2}{a^2} = \frac{a^2-c^2}{b^2}.$$

Applying [Componendo et dividendo](https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/componendo-et-dividendo/), these fractions are equal to

$$ \frac{ b^2-a^2+c^2-b^2+a^2-c^2} { c^2 + a^2 + b^2}$$

Hence, all of them are 0, which means $a=b=c$.

Comment: @math110 Judging from your comment on quarkine, is this the solution that you are thinking of? This is pretty 'nice', unless you want a more synthetic approach.

Comment: Yes,It's  very nice,and Thank you +1

Comment: and I think it maybe can use $$\dfrac{\sin{B}}{\sin{C}}\cos{A}=\dfrac{\sin{C}}{\sin{A}}\cos{B}=\dfrac{\sin{A}}{\sin{B}}\cos{C}$$

Comment: @math110 Thanks. The motivation behind this is that since the equations are not symmetric, looking at just 2 of them is not sufficient to conclude that $a=b$. Com et div is the simplest way to combine 3 fractions, which is why I thought about using it. It could be used initially, to show that each fraction is 1.

Comment: Oh,Thank you very much,I know,+1

Comment: When was you introduced to Componendo et dividendo? At junior high school, senior high school, university, or ?

Comment: @Marienplatz I participated in math olympiads, so I was introduced to the idea much earlier than normal. I'd say in grade 6-8 or so?

Comment: I see because I think most people don't know it.

Comment: @Marienplatz Yes, which is why I provided a link to explain what it is. It's not a standard technique taught to most high school students, but it's one that you will see in middle school math competitions. I also know OP's standard, based on questions that he has posed before.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:divide all the three by abc and then proceed.

Comment: this  idea is same as me.But Thank you